# Use JeroenvO/html5-colorpicker in React and Meteor project

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, meteor, canvas

I want to make a react component with this https://github.com/JeroenvO/html5-colorpicker

So I copied `colorPicker.js` and exported the constructor. Then I made a component like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import colorPicker from '../../../../../imports/colorPicker/colorPicker.js'

export default class ColorPicker extends Component {
  myDiv = null
  myPicker = null
  componentDidMount = () => {
    const { onColorChange } = this.props
    this.myPicker = new colorPicker(this.myDiv, {
        bgcolor: 'rgba(50,50,50,0)',
        onColorChange: function () {
          console.log('color in HSV', this.getColorHSV())
          console.log('color in HSL', this.getColorHSL())
          console.log('color in RGB', this.getColorRGB())
          onColorChange()
        },
        onCenterClick: function () {
              window.alert('You clicked the center!')
        }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <canvas ref={(elem) => this.myDiv = elem} width="500" height="500" id="colorPicker1"></canvas>
    )
  }
}
```

Then I get an error like this 
`Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.`

I guess I should also provide the images for the canvas as is in the repository. So I put the images where the `colorPicker.js` is located, in `imports/colorPicker`.
However I still get the same error. Somehow the image is not accessible if the problem is in the image at all. Can you help me with this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to just pass an image url as an option

`image: 'http://hayk94.gitlab.io/plain-html/color-500.png',`